# Change branch name when running custom build in Teamcity

Tags: teamcity

Given I have Teamcity job with Git VCS root with default branch which can be changed with `branch-name` parameter:

[image: default branch]

When I e.g. set `branch-name` to `develop` in admin screen, go back to build configuration home and run custom build where I change `branch-name` parameter to `master`
then I get:

[image: popup1]

[image: popup2]

Why is that?
What should I change, so that I don't get this message and I can change branch when running custom build?

The reason for this is I want to build and deploy software artifacts from any feature branch

Answer (score 3):

the Teamcity has an opportunity for monitoring the branches and runs built to custom branch.

Firstly, edit your **VCS Root** and add follows:

> Default branch: refs/heads/master
>   Branch specification:+:refs/heads/*

now the TC will check changes by some interval.

[image]

We are sets the master as default branch. and when we run the build with default parameters, the build will start to `master` branch

If you are want to start build with custom branch then press `Run...` -> Changes -> select your custom branch from `Build Branch` parameter.

[image]

If you want to run build from API, or want to reverse the build branch parameter, just set `Configuration parameters` with key `teamcity.build.branch`
 and value what you want