# Is it possible to create a project from Git without 'master' branch?

Tags: teamcity

I only have a `develop` branch in my repository at the moment.
When I try to create a project from it in Teamcity, I get the following error message:

> Cannot find revision of the default branch 'refs/heads/master' of vcs root 'dummy VCS root (jetbrains.git)'

The question i:s how can I create a TeamCity build from repo without master branch?  In Jenkins usually it makes no problem to build any branch

Comment: Every project should really have a "master" branch.  Maybe there's some way you can "get around it"; maybe your particular scenario is just a TeamCity restriction.  But in the long run, you'd just be causing yourself grief if you DIDN'T have a "master".

Comment: @paulsm4 from my point of view it is too early now. I will most probably squash all develop commits as an initial commit for master when ready

Comment: squash all develop commits -> master; push new master -> TeamCity origin: sounds like a good idea :)

Comment: Yes, you colud set any name as you wish. But always you need to identify some brach as 'main or default branch' . if you have just one branch, by definition is your 'default branch' .

Comment: So, in temacity change  vcs settings and set development instead of master. Master it's just a name... The important step, it's which branch you set as default or main in your repo

Comment: as it is quite ok with git, I think this is really teamcity specific, isn't it?

Comment: Check  first answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52150236/change-branch-name-when-running-custom-build-in-teamcity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. open attached VCS Roots of your project
2. Change `Default branch` to `refs/heads/develop`
3. `Branch specification` set to `+:refs/heads/*`

[image]

Now your default branch is `develop`, not a `master`. 
Also, you able to see all branches because of the Branch specification